# get data of a div when its top border touches the top of viewport

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

Three divs on a page - each of them has `100vh` height.

By scrolling up and down, I need to get `data-x` of a div when its top border touches the top of viewport.

And only when scrolling, not by loading the page.

In the example below on scrolling down console should be:

```
ipsum
dolor
```

and on scrolling back to top:

```
ipsum
lorem
```

Here is my try, but without success to get such a control.

please help

```js
var cards = [...document.querySelectorAll('.card')]

let options = {
    rootMargin: '100%'
};

function onIntersect(entries) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
        console.log(entry.target.dataset.x);
  });
}

const io = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersect, options)

cards.forEach((card) => {
    io.observe(card)
})
```

```css
.card{height:100vh;}
.carda{background:orange;}
.cardb{background:lightblue;}
.cardc{background:silver;}
```

```html
<div class='card carda' data-x='lorem'></div>
<div class='card cardb' data-x='ipsum'></div>
<div class='card cardc' data-x='dolor'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to detect if the page was `scrolled`, and `console.log` only that card which `isIntersecting`:

```js
var scrolled = false;
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => scrolled = true, {once: true});

var cards = [...document.querySelectorAll('.card')]

let options = {
  threshold: .7
};

function onIntersect(entries) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (scrolled && entry.isIntersecting) {
      console.log(entry.target.dataset.x);
    }
  });
}

const io = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersect, options)

cards.forEach((card) => {
  io.observe(card)
})
```

```css
.card {
  height: 100vh;
}

.carda {
  background: orange;
}

.cardb {
  background: lightblue;
}

.cardc {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class='card carda' data-x='lorem'></div>
<div class='card cardb' data-x='ipsum'></div>
<div class='card cardc' data-x='dolor'></div>
```

Comment: excellent, thanks a lot. BTW, what is the logic - `function onIntersect...` and `if entry.isIntersecting)` being together ? The first assumes the second, isn't it ?

Comment: @provance, happy to help! All the answers [are here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).